# Создание последовательных закладок при скролле часть 2

Tags: html, jquery, gsap

На данный момент реализован функцинал, который при скролле добавляет/убирает закладки title'ов. Всё правильно. Также использую библиотеку tweenmax, для создания анимации необходимых элементов. Но выливаются следующие нюансы/баги:
когда скроллим назад/вперед возле удаленного элемента он появляется с периодичность в 2-4 скролла. Не могу понять почему. Есть ли идеи? 
**UPD**
Проблема однозначно в GSAP'е. Но как ее решить?
[Пример на codepen](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/BKQdwO). И сам код:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('h2').each(function(i){
        var elementOnTop = $(this).offset().top,
            winSize = $(window).scrollTop(),
            title = $(this).text(),
            textId = 'title-' + i++ ,
            linkTo = $(this).attr('id');

        if (winSize > elementOnTop) {
            if ($('.marks a:contains('+ title + ')').length == 0) {
                $('.marks').append('<a href="#' + linkTo + '" id="' + textId + '">' + title + '</a>');
                TweenMax.from('#'+textId, 1, {y: -20, opacity: 0, ease:Elastic.easeOut, force3D:false}, 0.2);
            }

        } else {
            TweenMax.to('#'+textId, 1, {y: -20, opacity: 0, ease:Back.easeOut, force3D:false,  onComplete:function(){(this.target).remove()}});

        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Всегда добавляйте с хтмл.

Comment: Там есть пример на codepen.

Comment: Проблема решилась, меньшими задержками в анимации tweenmax'а. Пожалуй, нужно глубже изучать, что тут к чему.